# Is there a Windows API for adding badges to taskbar icons?

Tags: windows, taskbar, spotify

Spotify recently added a feature where the taskbar icon would have a red iOS-style badge with the number of songs in your inbox.

The badge itself is definitely part of the icon, but I was wondering if the number might be added with an official API.

If not, how might they be doing it? I've never had more than a few songs in my inbox, so maybe it just doesn't shows 1-9 and then 10+ or something, or could they be dynamically creating the image and setting it as the icon?

I wasn't aware you could change the icon while the app is running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ITaskBarList3::SetOverlayIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391696%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for.